# still error "multiple primary keys defined" when tables/databases are dropped

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I want to put my live site (wordpress) on localhost, so I exported the database (turning on the options for dropping database and tables) with phpmyadmin. When importing on localhost with BigDump I get the error message that "Multiple primary keys are defined". 
How can I solve this?

All the suggestions I have read so far say to drop the tables and/or database when exporting from live site. I did that but it makes no difference. What else can I do to succesfully import the DB on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Check your create table statements in exported file. May be somewhere in your create statemate two primary keys are defined.

A table can have only one primary key, which may consist of single or multiple fields. When multiple fields are used as a primary key, they are called a composite key.

If possible cereate database and tables manually and remove table creation statements from expoted file and you can source only data from the file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I could not find multiple primary keys for the table. I exported the database and tried with any/all of the options "drop table", "drop database", "empty table before importing" turned on (besides the standard options which are turned on). Error is still the same:

ADD KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191));
ALTER TABLE `wp_commentmeta`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
ADD KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
ADD KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
MySQL: Multiple primary key defined